# What is a covariant return type?

Tags: java, oop, covariance

What is a covariant return type in Java?  In object-oriented programming in general?

Comment: this blog post(https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java) explains, just adding up to knowledge base here.

Comment: @AkhilJain: That blog post is brilliant and simple.  It is the very best explanation-by-example I have ever seen for how Java supports covariant return types.

Comment: @kevinarpe thanks, I am glad it is helpful to so many people.

Comment: @Manash Covariant return type basically used in Runtime Polymorphism when methods are override and that override can allowed methods to return same class object  return type or subclass return type can be allowed.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Covariant return, means that when one overrides a method, the return type of the overriding method is allowed to be a subtype of the overridden method's return type.

To clarify this with an example, a common case is `Object.clone()` - which is declared to return a type of `Object`.  You could override this in your own class as follows:

```
public class MyFoo
{

   ...

   // Note covariant return here, method does not just return Object
   public MyFoo clone()
   {
       // Implementation
   }
}
```

The benefit here is that any method which holds an explicit reference to a MyFoo object will be able to invoke `clone()` and know (without casting) that the return value is an instance of `MyFoo`.  Without covariant return types, the overridden method in MyFoo would have to be declared to return `Object` - and so calling code would have to explicitly downcast the result of the method call (even thought both sides "know" it can only ever be an instance of MyFoo).

Note that there's nothing special about `clone()` and that any overridden method can have a covariant return - I used it as an example here as it's a standard method where this is often useful.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be related with `List<Foo>` and `List<FooBar>` ?

Comment: That's covariant types in a broader sense rather than just the covariant **return** type asked about here.  It is the same underlying principle, though - you can think of the top-level  definition of `clone()` as being a `Method<Void, Object>`, and asking whether the more specific `Method<Void, MyFoo>` is assignable to that parent type.  Which it is, if and only if Java methods are covariant in their return type.

Answer (score 49):

Here is another simple example :

`Animal` class

```
public class Animal {

    protected Food seekFood() {

        return new Food();
    }
}
```

`Dog` class

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    protected Food seekFood() {

        return new DogFood();
    }
}
```

It’s possible to modify the return type of the `Dog`’s `seekFood()` method to `DogFood` - a subclass of `Food`, as shown below:

```
@Override
protected DogFood seekFood() {

    return new DogFood();
}
```

That’s perfectly a legal overriding, and the return type of `Dog`’s `seekFood()` method is known as **covariant return type**.

Answer (score 10):

From the release of JDK 1.5, covariant types were introduced in Java. and I'll explain it to you with a simple case, : *When we override a function the function is allowed to make changes to it's behaviour* that's what you get to read in most of the books, but what they { authors } miss out on is that we can change the return type too. 
check below link for clarification we can change the return type as long as it can be assigned to return type of Base version of the method.

So this feature of returning derived types is called COVARIANT...

[Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type)

Answer (score 9):

covariant Return types simply means returning own Class reference or its child class reference.

```
class Parent {
 //it contain data member and data method
}

class Child extends Parent { 
//it contain data member and data method
 //covariant return
  public Parent methodName() {
     return new Parent();
          or 
     return Child();
  }

}
```

Comment: It also includes the case where `Parent.foo()` returns an _unrelated_ type `A` and `Child.foo()` returns a type `B` derived from `A`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answers, overriding is possible among co-variant return types, with the constraint that the return type of the overriding method (subclass method) should be a subclass of the return type of the overridden method (superclass method). This is valid from Java 5 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Covariant return type specifies that the return type may vary in the same direction as the subclass

```
class One{  
    One get(){return this;}  
}  

class Two extends One{  
  Two get(){return this;}  

void message(){
  System.out.println("After Java5 welcome to covariant return type");
}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
    new Two().get().message();  
}  
}
```

Before Java 5, it was not possible override any method 
by changing the return type. But now, since Java5,

it is possible to override method by changing the return type 
if subclass overrides any method 
whose return type is Non-Primitive 
but it changes its return type to subclass type.

Answer (score 1):

- It helps to avoid confusing type casts present in the class hierarchy
  and thus making the code readable, usable and maintainable.
- We get a liberty to have more specific return types when overriding
  methods.
- Help in preventing run-time ClassCastExceptions on    returns

*reference: 
www.geeksforgeeks.org*

Answer (score 0):

> - The covariant return type in java, allows narrowing down return type
>     of the overridden method.
> - This feature will help to avoid down casting
>     on the client side. It allows programmer to program without the need
>     of type checking and down casting.
> - The covariant return type always
>     works only for non-primitive return types.

```
interface Interviewer {
    default Object submitInterviewStatus() {
        System.out.println("Interviewer:Accept");
        return "Interviewer:Accept";
    }
}
class Manager implements Interviewer {
    @Override
    public String submitInterviewStatus() {
        System.out.println("Manager:Accept");
        return "Manager:Accept";
    }
}
class Project {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Interviewer interviewer = new Manager();
        interviewer.submitInterviewStatus();
        Manager mgr = new Manager();
        mgr.submitInterviewStatus();
    }
}
```

> Other example is from Java,

UnaryOperator.java

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface UnaryOperator<T> extends Function<T, T> {

    /**
     * Returns a unary operator that always returns its input argument.
     *
     * @param <T> the type of the input and output of the operator
     * @return a unary operator that always returns its input argument
     */
    static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
}
```

Function.java

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> {

    ........
    ........
    ........
    ........

    static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before Java5, it was not possible to override any method by changing the return type. But now, since Java5, it is possible to override method by changing the return type if subclass overrides any method whose return type is Non-Primitive but it changes its return type to subclass type.