# Covariant return type & throws declaration

Tags: java, javac, throws, covariant-return-types

In this below hierarchy,

### [image]

Below is the compiled code, for this question:

```
class T3 {}
class T2 extends T3{}
class T1 extends T2{}
class T5 extends T1{}

class E3 extends Throwable {}
class E2 extends E3 {}
class E1 extends E2 {}
class E5 extends E1 {}

interface I1{
    T1 m() throws E1;
}

interface I2{
    T2 m() throws E2;
}

interface I3{
    T3 m() throws E3;
}

interface I4 extends I1, I2, I3{

}

interface I5 extends I1, I2, I3{
    T5 m() throws E5;
}
```

In the above code, `interface I4` and `interface I5` get compiled because,

1)

`interface I4 extends I1, I2, I3` only when,

`T1 extends T2` & `T1 extends T3` & `T2 extends T3`

and

`E1 extends E2` & `E1 extends E3` & `E2 extends E3`.

2)

`interface I5 extends I1, I2, I3` and overrides `m()` as `T5 m() throws E5;` only when,

`T5 extends T1` & `T5 extends T2` & `T5 extends T3`

and

`E5 extends E1` & `E5 extends E2` & `E5 extends E3`.

With respect to *covariant return types* & *throws declaration* aspect,

Can I say that, the code compiled successfully because above two rules are valid and necessary?

Comment: Here are some relevant posts: [covariant return types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type) and [`throws` declaration in overridden methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/why-cant-overriding-methods-throw-exceptions-broader-than-the-overriden-method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say the code compiled correctly because those rules are valid and necessary.

If T5 did not extend T1, T2, and T3 then I4 and I5 would not compile.

If E5 did not extend E1, E2, and E3 then I5 would not compile (I4 would continue to compile because in theory an implementer of I4 could create their own exception class which extended E1, E2, and E3).

Comment: if you are not sure what the question is, please see the query edit

Comment: @overexchange You should clarify your question instead of criticizing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code get compiled because Java allows [covarient return type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html):

- This technique, called covariant return type, means that the return type is allowed to vary in the same direction as the subclass.
- Liskov substitution principle: [Liskov's notion of a behavioral subtype defines a notion of substitutability for objects; that is, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46861844/8389458)

Here are the UML Diagrams of your code:

`I4` interface has 3 method `m()` but their return type is different.
`I5` interface has 4 method `m()` and their return type is also different.

[image: Class Hierarchy]
[image: I4]
[image: I5]