# Why in java method overriding allows to have covariant return types, but not covariant parameters?

Tags: java, covariant

For example I have a Processor base class with a method that returns an Object and takes Object as a parameter. I want to extend it and create a StringProcessor which will return String and take String as parameter. However
covariant typing is only allowed with return value, but not parameter. What is the reason for such limitations?

```
class Processor {
    Object process (Object input) {
        //create a copy of input, modify it and return it
        return copy;
    }
}

class StringProcessor extends Processor {
    @Override
    String process (String input) { // permitted for parameter. why?
        //create a copy of input string, modify it and return it
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

[The Liskov principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). When designing the Processor class, you write a contract saying: "a Processor is able to take any Object as argument, and to return an Object".

The StringProcessor is a Processor. So it's supposed to obey that contract. But if it only accepts String as argument, it violates that contract. Remember: a Processor is supposed to accept any Object as argument.

So you should be able to do:

```
StringProcessor sp = new StringProcessor();
Processor p = sp; // OK since a StringProcessor is a Processor
p.process(new Integer(3456));
```

When returning a String, it doesn't violate the contract: it's supposed to return an Object, a String is an Object, so everything is fine.

You can do what you want to achieve by using generics:

```
class Processor<T> {
    Object process (T input) {
        //create a copy of input, modify it and return it
        return copy;
    }
}

class StringProcessor extends Processor<String> {
    @Override
    String process (String input) { 
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want a type-theoretical answer, the reason for this is, when considering the subtyping relation on function types, the relation is covariant on return types, but **contravariant** on argument types (i.e. `X -> Y` is a subtype of `U -> W` if `Y` is a subtype of `W` and `U` is a subtype of `X`).