# Kotlin properties cannot be overridden with subinterface

Tags: inheritance, interface, kotlin

In the following stripped down example, can you explain why the Kotlin compiler complains when overriding a that we restrict its type further(compiler message: `Var-property type is 'B', which is not a type of overriden public abstract var a: A`)

```
interface A

interface B : A {
    fun someFunc():Boolean
}

class C : B {
    override fun someFunc(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}

abstract class D {
    abstract var a: A
}

class E : D() {
    override var a : B = C()

    fun otherFunc() {
        println(a.someFunc())
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the compiler does not complain with the following snippet:

```
open class G

class H : G()

abstract class F {
    abstract val g: G
}

class I : F() {
    override var g : H = H()
}
```

So I guess there is something going on with interface inheritance, which is not there with classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code snippet fails to compile, because otherwise weirdness like this would be possible:

```
val d: D = E()
d.a = object : A {}  // Some other sub-type of A, but definitely not a sub-type of B
```

This is really a variant (no pun intended) of the [lack of method parameter covariance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861804/why-in-java-method-overriding-allows-to-have-covariant-return-types-but-not-cov) - especially given that a Kotlin `var` property is really just syntax sugar for a getter and setter method.

Conversely, your second snippet *does* compile because in this case, covariance isn't a problem - there's no setter in the base class (`F`) to be overriden, so the "weirdness" I described above isn't possible.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen - The problem here is really down to the mutability (i.e. the fact that you can *set* the property via a base-class reference).  So one solution is to make it a `val` property.  But I suppose another workaround is to use generics - i.e. `abstract class D<T : A> { abstract var a: T }` and `class E : D<B>() { override var a : B = C() }`.  That won't be appropriate in all cases, though.