# Can I use generic type with @Entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm defining generic @MappedSuperclass for future usage. In my experience all categories has same code. Then I think I can create generic Category and multiple sub classes. But hibernate can't fetch children and can't update PageCategory. I need to know it is invalid or hibernate bug?

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Cacheable
public abstract class Category<T extends Category> {

private Integer id;

private String name;

private T parent;

private List<T> children;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Transient
public T getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(T parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@Transient
public List<T> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(List<T> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pageCategory")
public class PageCategory extends Category<PageCategory> implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
@Override
public PageCategory getParent() {
    return super.getParent();
}

@OrderBy("name asc")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@Override
public List<PageCategory> getChildren() {
    return super.getChildren();
}
}
```

Comment: What you post suggests that you want that field to be transient (not persistent) in the root and persistent in the subclass. Confirm this is what you mean. Use of generics ought to be possible in JPA models

Comment: @NeilStockton I think some sub classes can ignore parent, child inheritance. In my case PageCategory overridden getter method.

Comment: so your question is nothing to do with generics and everything to do with you thinking you can override the TRANSIENT annotation when used with subclasses. Perhaps rewrite your question to say that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use generics with @Entity, but in your case you don't need generic class.

An overridden method may have a more specific return type. That is, as long as the new return type is assignable to the return type of the method you are overriding.

```
public class A {    
    public A get(){
        return null;
    }    
    public List<? extends A> list(){
        return null;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
        @Override
        public B get() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<B> list(){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is called "Covariant return type": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type