# Diamond issue with common default method in interfaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-management, java-8

I am trying to understand why the below program does not compile.
The return type of both default methods is different in both interfaces.
Should they be treated as two different methods in interface c?

```
interface a{
    default void log(String str){
        System.out.println("I1 logging::"+str);
    }  
}

interface b {
    default int log(String str){
        System.out.println("I1 logging::"+str);
        return 0;
    }
}

interface c extends a,b{
}
```

HelloWorld.java:32: error: types b and a are incompatible; both define log(java.lang.String), but with unrelated return types interface c extends a,b{ }

Answer (score 1):

Your default implementations are neither following overriding (maintaining co-variant return types) nor overloading (difference in parameters).

Refer this for more information:

[Covariant return types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type)

[What is a covariant return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they
>   have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and,
>   after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type
>   parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

Your interfaces contains methods with same signature (same method name and parameter type)

> It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with
>   override-equivalent signatures in a class.

Hence you cannot implement both interface in your class. (Indeed, the compiler cannot distinguish functions just by return type_)