# Is there a way to implicitly cast as a subtype in the method that returns itself?

Tags: java, grammar

```
    public class Main {
        public static class SuperClass {
            public SuperClass returnThis () {
                return this;
            }
        }
        
        public static class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
            @Override
            public SubClass1 returnThis () {
                return this;
            }
        }
        
        public static class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
            @Override
            public SubClass2 returnThis () {
                return this;
            }
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SubClass1 sub1 = new SubClass1().returnThis();
            SubClass2 sub2 = new SubClass2().returnThis();
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the example I need to define returnThis() method to get a subtype instance. Is there any beautiful way to make it so that I don't have to create returnThis() for every subclass?

```
    public class Main {
        public static class SuperClass<T extends SuperClass<?>> {
            public T returnThis () {
                return (T)this;
            }
        }
        
        public static class SubClass1 extends SuperClass<SubClass1> {
        }
        
        public static class SubClass2 extends SuperClass<SubClass2> {
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SubClass1 sub1 = new SubClass1().returnThis();
            SubClass2 sub2 = new SubClass2().returnThis();
        }
    }
```

I also tried using generic but it doesn't look so good

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't look so good"? What kind of code "looks good" to you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, covariant return types are allowed.  Can you elaborate further? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type

Comment: Why do you need such a method anyway? This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `new SubClass1().returnThis()` seems a really complex way of doing `new SubClass()`.  The result of both of these are the same. Can you provide more details about what the original problem is that you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: The other way to do this involves generics, so if that isn’t sufficiently beautiful for you, you’re out of luck.

Comment: I have a builder class and many other classes that extend that builder class. I have to override all methods defined in the super builder class to achieve a covariant return because they return the builder instance as a supertype. I want to know if there's any solution for this so I don't have to rewrite every method in superclass again.