# Problem Inheritance, I don't understand cloning between the cloning order

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I hope you are well, I have a question regarding the following code, because when instantiating the object in the manner

```java
Vehicle v = new Vehicle(4);
Vehicle w = (Vehicle) v.clone();
```

It works, but when I instantiate it like this it doesn't work for me:

```java
Truck s = new Truck(4);
Truck t = (Truck) s.clone();
```

(Could you explain to me in "Easy" words because I still don't understand all the concepts very well) (If I'm not wrong, it's a problem with casting, I think, or it could be due to cloning the object twice.)

(If I'm not wrong, it's a problem with casting, I think, or it could be due to cloning the object twice.)

```java
class Vehicle implements Cloneable {
    private int x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Truck s = new Truck(4);
        Truck t = (Truck) s.clone();
    }

    public Vehicle(int y) {
        x = y;
    }

    public Object clone() {
        Object result = new Vehicle(this.x);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```java
class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private int y;

    public Truck(int z) {
        super(z);
        y = z;
    }

    public Object clone() {
        Truck result = (Truck) super.clone();
        result.y = this.y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What do you mean by "works"/"doesn't work"?

Comment: Please upload the source code as the plain text format

Comment: Please [format as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362) the code in your question.

Comment: The result of a `super.clone()` in `Truck` is an instance of `Vehicle`, not `Truck`, so the cast will fail - you'd be better calling the `Truck`s constructor

Comment: Why the close votes? The full source code is there, albeit not in text form. The question is clear, and I was able to answer it. Cut the newbie some slack, would you?

Answer (score 2):

#### Original code and its problems

Like *Madprogrammer* said, `super.clone()` returns a `Vehicle` instance. In Java, you can cast a subclass to its superclass, but not the other way around. That makes sense from an OOP perspective. A truck is a vehicle, but not every vehicle is a truck. The problem with the `clone()` method is that, in order to work for every class, it returns `Object`, i.e. the compiler cannot help you there, and you need to know what you are doing. Therefore, you get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Vehicle cannot be cast to class Truck (Vehicle and Truck are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at Truck.clone(Vehicle_77164962.java:28)
    at Vehicle.main(Vehicle_77164962.java:6)
```

#### Improvements, step 1

You can, however, use [covariant overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882587/1082681) and make your `clone()` methods return more specific types. Then you do not need to cast to and from `Object` anymore. That does not solve your problem here, but helps you as guide rails in your programs.

What really solves the problem is to actually construct a `Truck` instead of a `Vehicle` that does not know anything about the specialisations of `Truck`. Credits also go to *Madprogrammer*.

Your example code is kind of cryptic with regard to field naming, and the subclass constructor puts the same field value in both the superclass's `x` and its own `y` fields. To make it more illustrative, I changed your code a bit:

```java
class Vehicle implements Cloneable {
    protected String name;

    public Vehicle(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle clone() {
        return new Vehicle(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Truck truck = new Truck("ACME mark IV", 8);
        System.out.println("Original: " + truck);
        System.out.println("Clone:    " + truck.clone());
    }
}
```

```java
class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private int numberOfWheels;

    public Truck(String name, int numberOfWheels) {
        super(name);
        this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
    }

    @Override
    public Truck clone() {
        return new Truck(name, numberOfWheels);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Truck{name='" + name + "', numberOfWheels=" + numberOfWheels + '}';
    }
}
```

Running the code, yields the following console output:

```
Original: Truck{name='ACME mark IV', numberOfWheels=8}
Clone:    Truck{name='ACME mark IV', numberOfWheels=8}
```

#### Improvements, step 2

If you read the [javadoc for `Object.clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--), you will notice that actually, you do not need to create objects by yourself, if you call `super.clone()`. In your original code, you tried that in the subclass, but the parent class did not obey to that rule, so it did not work. Let us change the code again and fix it:

```java
class Vehicle implements Cloneable {
    protected String name;

    public Vehicle(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Vehicle) super.clone();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Truck truck = new Truck("ACME mark IV", 8);
        System.out.println("Original: " + truck);
        System.out.println("Clone:    " + truck.clone());
    }
}
```

```java
class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private int numberOfWheels;

    public Truck(String name, int numberOfWheels) {
        super(name);
        this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
    }

    @Override
    public Truck clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Truck) super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Truck{name='" + name + "', numberOfWheels=" + numberOfWheels + '}';
    }
}
```

Now, you need to cast a little bit again for the covariant overrides to work, and you correctly declare the super method's `CloneNotSupportedException`, but now you have a canonical Java solution.

The console log is exactly as before.

Please note: If you do not need or want the covariant overrides and are content with the `clone` methods returning `Object` and are willing to cast the results by yourself, you do not need to override `Object.clone()` at all. The code will still work except for the casting overhead.